# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} *[ \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}]$

Tags: limits

I have this problem and I really don't know, how to edit it to get some solution.
$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt{n} * [\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}]$

So my question Is what to do with $\sqrt{n} * [\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}]$?

Comment: As a start, you might consider bounding the expression, say by $\sqrt n(\sqrt n-\sqrt n)\le \sqrt n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)\le (\sqrt{n+1})^2-n=1$...

Answer (score 2):

Set $1/n=h$ to find

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}h$$

Now rationalize the numerator

Or

choose $\sqrt{1+h}=k\implies h=k^2-1$

Comment: Why?I don't have any division here.

Comment: @LSpy, try the replacement yourself

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt n =\frac {1}{\sqrt {n+1}+\sqrt n}$$

Thus the desired limit is $$\lim _{n\to \infty} \frac {\sqrt n }{\sqrt {n+1}+\sqrt n} = 1/2$$

Comment: why is it 1/2? I understand all the steps before but not how to get the number?

Comment: The bottom is equivalent to $2\sqrt n$ which makes fraction goes to 1/2

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$$\sqrt n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)=\sqrt n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}=$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}=\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $ \dfrac {\sqrt {n+1} +√n}{\sqrt{n+1}+√n}=1 $ yields :

$a_n:= \dfrac{√n}{\sqrt{n+1}+√n}.$

$\dfrac{√n}{2\sqrt{n+1}} \lt a_n \lt \dfrac{√n}{2√n}=1/2$

$\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{1+1/n}} \lt a_n \lt 1/2.$

Take the limit $n \rightarrow \infty.$