# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n} \cdot \left(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}\right)=\frac12$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

This is a very unspecific and maybe stupid question, so I apologize for that. We recently had an exam that I failed, because I had pretty much no time to practice before that. Now I got to learn all that stuff that I should've known, yet there was one exercise where I have no clue how one would get a result.

> Calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n} \cdot (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}).$$

The solution appears to be $\frac{1}{2}$, however I have exactly no clue on how to get to that.

If someone could throw a keyword at me, that would lead me on my path, it could already be very helpful.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/220196/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136495/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2980446/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%20%5Ccdot%20(%5Csqrt%7Bn%2B1%7D%20-%20%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D).%24&p=1)

Comment: @MartinR Seems like. Sorry for that, but I didn't find it when I was searching (probably due to formatting of the title) Edit: Will use Approach0 in the future - didn't know there was such thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}=\frac1{\sqrt n}\times\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}+1}.$

Comment: Now I got it, thank you very much. (Also thank you for beautifying my question, I didn't know you could use MathJax in the title aswell)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\dfrac{n+1-n}{?}$$

Now set $1/n=h,h\to0^+$

Alternatively

$$\sqrt n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}{h}$$

Set $\sqrt{1+h}=u$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n} \cdot (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})}{1}=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n})}{(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n})}=
 \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n}\cdot \frac{n+1-n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}=
 \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n}\cdot \frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt n}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}+1}= \frac1{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{\dfrac 1h+1}-\sqrt{\dfrac 1h}}{\sqrt h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{h+1}-1}h=\left.(\sqrt{x+1})'\right|_{x=0}=\frac12.$$